# JenkinsFile, aproaching to enviroment dependent

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm new on Jenkins and I don't know how to approach to a multi-environment jenkinsfile.

**Note**: I'm using multibranch pipeline

Firstly I thought about writing 3 different files of Jenkins, depending of the branch. But, I think there must be another way to do it with only 1 Jenkinsfile which could execute different process depending of the branch you are working on.

Something like:

```
if branch == 'master' then
  procces to do
else if branch == 'test' then
  other proccess
else
  process for developer branch
```

**edit**:

I found that there's the possibility of using env variables. I tried:

```
echo "$BRANCH_NAME"
echo "$env.BRANCH_NAME"
echo 'BRANCH NAME: ' + env.BRANCH_NAME
echo ${env.BRANCH_NAME}
echo "${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
...
```

but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Jenkins you use `when` clauses to define when stages should be run

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
      stage("Release if Required") {
            when {
                anyOf {
                    branch 'master'
                    branch 'main'
                }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    publishRelease()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to do the check while in the steps you can use the environment vars

```
script {
    if(env.BRANCH_NAME =~ 'master' || env.BRANCH_NAME =~ 'main') {
        echo "On the main branch"            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was not using it on `script {` section.

```sh
stage('Checkout code') {
  script {
   echo "${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
   if ("master" == env.BRANCH_NAME) {
    do something
    ...
   } else if ("Test" == env.BRANCH_NAME) {
    do something
    ...
   } else {
    do something
    ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so mutch @apr_1985, your answer is a better option than using only script :D